# Ensuring rabbitmq cluster nodes are communicating through ssl

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I have setup the Rabbitmq cluster with two nodes deployed in two different machines.

I followed the steps in the [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering-ssl.html) to make the communication across the nodes through SSL. I'm able to run through the steps without any issue.

Now that, I have completed the steps, how can I ensure that communication across cluster nodes is happening over SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture packets in wireshark in the port you set for inter-node communication (by default it is 25672).

Then see in the wireshark capture if the protocol is SSL